# How to use Django sessions

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django and i'm trying to build a Todo app with user authentication but i want to add sessions to it whereby everyone can have different tasks attached to their accounts but i don't know how to go about it. I've checked the Django documentation on it but i still don't get it.

Here's my models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


# Create your models here.

class Task(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class User(AbstractUser):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, null=True)
    bio = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

    USERNAME_FIELDS = "email"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
```

Then here's my view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import Task, User
from .forms import AddTaskForm 

@login_required(login_url="loginPage")
def home(request):
    tasks = Task.objects.all()

    context = {"tasks": tasks, }
    return render(request, "task/home.html", context)


# Add task view
@ login_required(login_url="loginPage")
def addTask(request):
    addTaskForm = AddTaskForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        addTaskForm = AddTaskForm(request.POST)
        if addTaskForm.is_valid():
            addTaskForm.save()
            return redirect('home')

    context = {"addTaskForm": addTaskForm}
    return render(request, "task/addtask.html", context)


# Update task view
@login_required(login_url="loginPage")
def update(request, pk):
    updateTask = Task.objects.get(id=pk)
    updateTaskForm = AddTaskForm(instance=updateTask)

    if request.method == "POST":
        updateTaskForm = AddTaskForm(request.POST, instance=updateTask)
        if updateTaskForm.is_valid():
            updateTaskForm.save()
            return redirect('home')

    context = {"updateTaskForm": updateTaskForm}
    return render(request, "task/update-task.html", context)



# Delete task view
@ login_required(login_url="loginPage")
def delete(request, pk):
    deleteTask = Task.objects.get(id=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        deleteTask.delete()
        return redirect("home")

    context = {"deleteTask": deleteTask}
    return render(request, "task/delete-task.html", context)
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't need to go with sessions. You need to improve model using Django ORM.

Like:

```
#models.py
class User(AbstractUser):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, null=True)
    bio = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

    USERNAME_FIELDS = "email"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

class Task(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

While saving tasks in Task model, provide the id of the user in the user field.

Answer (score 0):

check this simple use of sessions in django :

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from django import forms
from django.urls import reverse

class NewTaskForm(forms.Form) :
    task = forms.CharField(label="Add Task ")

# Create your views here.
Tasks = []

def index(request) :
    if "Tasks" not in request.session :
        request.session["Tasks"] = []
    return render(request , "tasks/index.html",{
        "tasks" : request.session["Tasks"]
    })

def add(request) : 
    if request.method == "POST" :
        form = NewTaskForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid() : 
            task = form.cleaned_data["task"]
            request.session["Tasks"] += [task]
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
        else : 
            return render(request , "tasks/add.html" , {
                "form" : form 
            })
    
    return render(request , "tasks/add.html" ,{
        "form" : NewTaskForm()
    })
```

with this method each user views their own task lists, i have a project same as what you looking for, [here](https://github.com/0x27752357/cs50w-Task-list-with-sessions/tree/main/tasks)

Comment: Are you both taking the same course by any chance? It wouldn't be smart for you / good for him if you would have an identical solutions on the exam ;-).

btw, don't put sqlite, .DS_Store and pycache to the git repository

Comment: Hi, Yes i guess, it is cs50 web development intro project, can i ask why shouldn't put DS_Store and pycache in my project ?

Comment: They are just not related to the project sources and pollute the repository with unneeded binary data. It is important to maintain a clear history of the code changes in repository to be able to find/review when and why the code became what it is, and the blobs wouldn't help you in this.

Comment: thank you sir, i'll delete them from now on